# Encription Output beautifier

Tags: c#, encryption, base64, user-input, base32

I'm searching for an option to have an encrypted string to be an clean and easy input from keyboard.

Algorithm of encryption could variate (blowfish, rijndael, serpent, or another one)

The best solution until now is transforming the encryption result into base32 I will get "A-Z", "2-7" and "=" for padding, replaced by myself with "0; 1; 8" randomly.
Is there any other option to get only letters and numbers ideally upper+numbers or upper+lower+numbers from base64.

Or sort of naming convention procedure to transform the encrypted string into beautified output for user, not a problem if extra characters are added.

This is nothing then a nice and simple way of imputing by typing for user, has a lot to do with security but that layer is deeper in the logic and is a nice to have feature.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hexadecimal encoding also known as [Base16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding#Encoding_standards). This will make textual representation of binary twice longer than original data (50%), which is less efficient than Base32 (62.5%).

Comment: Yes I know about this, but I wasn't aware of the size length percentage, witch make sense, Thank you.

Comment: When user inputs something, then data length matters. But in some cases data length can be neglected.